# Duration calc works in editor but doesn't load in worksheet

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm loading data from .CSV files, and calculating a duration. The duration shows up fine in the query editor, but when loading to a worksheet, it shows as blank. This is what it looks like in the Query Editor:
[image]
and this is what the resulting spreadsheet looks like: [image]

Notice that the time difference in minutes is calculated correctly, and does transfer to the spreadsheet.

Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Here is the PowerQuery:

```
/*
    Step0_AllRawData - Load data from files in a folder
    The named range "SourceDirectory" must contain the full path to the directory holding the source .CSV files
*/
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\Dee\Desktop\Alice Pharmacy\Ihab\DataFiles-NewFormat"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(
        Source, 
        each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File (4)", 
        each #"Transform File (4)"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(
        #"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(
        #"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File (4)"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File (4)", 
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File (4)"(#"Sample File (4)"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Expanded Table Column1",{
            {"Source.Name", type text}, 
            {"DistrictNumber", Int64.Type}, 
            {"ArrivalTime", type datetime}, 
            {"DisposedDateTime", type datetime}, 
            {"DrugName", type text}, 
            {"prescribedate", type datetime}, 
            {"PrescribedBy", type text}, 
            {"AdministeredDt", type datetime}, 
            {"AdministeredDt1", type datetime}, 
            {"AdministeredBy", type text}, 
            {"drugoutcome", type text}, 
            {"FinalText", type text}, 
            {"", type text}}),
            // Calculate DayOfWeek and time delays...
     #"Add DayOfWeek" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type", 
        "DayOfWeek", 
        each Date.DayOfWeekName([prescribedate]), type text),
    #"Add TimeDelayHours" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Add DayOfWeek", 
        "TimeDelayHours", 
        each (([AdministeredDt]-[prescribedate])), type time ),
    #"Add TimeDelayMins" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Add TimeDelayHours", 
        "TimeDelayMins", 
        each (([AdministeredDt]-[prescribedate]) * 1440), type number ),
    #"Changed ToNumber" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Add TimeDelayMins",{
            {"TimeDelayMins", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
        #"Changed ToNumber",{
            {"DrugName", "Prescription"}, 
            {"prescribedate", "PrescribeDate"}, 
            {"AdministeredDt", "AdministeredDate"}}),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(
        #"Renamed Columns",{"DistrictNumber", "PrescribedBy", "AdministeredBy", "AdministeredDt1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, TimeDelayMins is formatted as a number but TimeDelayHours is formatted as time. If you format your output excel table properly then the TimeDelayHours column will show the data. Alternatively, in powerquery, convert the TimeDelayHours column to a number and change the column format to a number before loading to excel

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to set the datatype to `Duration` in the Query Editor.